# When I return a string from my function, it has commas with it?

Tags: python, string

I have written a function to return a string with a condition is false, but everytime it returns it, there are commas in the string. I don't know why.

```
key = 0

test_dictionary = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'} 

def show_value(a, b):
    for item in b:
        if item == a:
            return(b[a])
    if key == 0:
        return(a, str('is not a valid key'))
```

Comment: return(a, str('is not a valid key')) is returning a tuple of `a` and the string that is why you are seeing a comma.

Comment: Dictionary `.get()` does the exact operation your function does. Yours is too much convoluted code.

Comment: Why are you looping through a dictionary instead of just `if a in b:`?

Comment: I'm a huge noob guys so I'm not familiar with a lot a syntax tbh. Thanks for the tips though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return(a, "is not a valid key")` returns a tuple.

Instead, do `return(str(a) + " is not a valid key")`

Edit : Other answers are very interesting, i'll summarize them here.

First, a pythonic way to insert variables in strings is 
`'{} is not a valid key'.format(a)`.

Since 3.6, you can use an "f" string, which permit cleaner insertions : `f"{a} is not a valid key"`.

Finally, you can replace your answer with the `dict.get(key,message_to_display_if_key_not_found)` attribute, which does exactly what you want. You can even throw an exception message : final code would then be :

`return b.get(a, f"{a} is not a valid key")`

Answer (score 4):

running `show_value(5, test_dictionary)` gets me `(5, 'is not a valid key')`. Which doesn't have added commas in your string., if you want a string that looks like a sentence try:

```
def show_value(a, b):

    for item in b:

        if item == a:


            return(b[a])

    if key == 0:

        return "{} is not a valid key".format(a)
```

if you want to be really fancy you could use:

```
key = 0
test_dictionary = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'} 
def show_value(a, b):
    return b.get(5, "{} is not a valid key".format(a))
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why it returns it with commas though. Usually when I print a string it just looks like a sentence.

Comment: You are returning a tuple with `return(a, str('is not a valid key'))`. this isn't a string, its a different data type; you are essentially making something very similar to a list. `"{} is not a valid key".format(a)` is a string, so it doesn't have commas

Comment: You aren't returning a *string*; you are returning a tuple and getting the string representation of that tuple.

Comment: If you thinking of `print(a, 'is not a valid key')`, that's *completely* different; `print` *outputs* each string to standard output separated by a space; it doesn't *return* anything.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are returning a tuple, `(a, "is not a valid key")`, instead of a string. Asumming you are using Python 3.6+, you can use an f-string:

```
return f'{a} is not a valid key'
```

As suggested by @MasonCaiby, you can use `get` method of a dictionary to return a value when there is not value associated with a key, and also combine the f-string:

```
return b.get(5, f"{a} is not a valid key")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code returns a tuple not a string when key == 0. 
Furthermore, you probably don't correctly iterate the dictionary.

It works, it's very bad, but maybe that's what you wanted to write:

```
def show_value(k, _dict):
    for key, value in _dict.items():
        if value == k:
            return _dict[key] 
        if key == 0:
            return "{}is not a valid key".format(key)
```

But are you sure you approached the problem the right way?

If you want safe access to the dictionary, you can do it:

```
test_dictionary = {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'} 
key = 0

if key in test_dictionary:
    # do somethings with test_dictionary[key]
    print(test_dictionary[key])
else:
    print('is not a valid key')
```

Comment: is it not `if key in test_dictionary.keys()` ?

Comment: In Python 3 `if key in test_dictionary` is equal to `if key in test_dictionary.keys()` :)

Comment: Also, if you try to do tests, `if key in test_dictionary` is much more efficient.